# I2C and ADC using PIC18F2458 with MikroC

Tags: microcontroller, usb, pic, i2c

I'm using the following USB Joystick with I2C for PIC18F2458 using MikroC.
Right now the USB works only if I disable the I2C.
Running USB + I2C, halts on I2C1_Start(); in the Debugger and even in Proteus simulation.

```
void main(void){
                               

  ADCON1  = 0x07;                       


  HID_Enable(&readbuff,&writebuff);       // Enable HID communication
  TRISB.B0 = 0x0; // I2C SCL, Data
  TRISB.B1 = 0x0;

  //vl6180x_configure();
  I2C1_Init(100000);
  I2C1_Start();

  while(1){
  analogo();
  USB_Polling_Proc();

    writebuff[0]=usb[0];
    writebuff[1]=usb[1];        //EJE X
    writebuff[2]=usb[2];        //EJE Y
    writebuff[3]=0;
    writebuff[4]=0;                //    kk = HID_Read();


    HID_Write(&writebuff,5);

   }

}
```

Schematic:

also note that error

Spurious SCL transition detected at 0.001206s [$II2C DEBUGGER#0003]

[image]

Updated schematic

[image]

Comment: The PIC has an internal 3.3V regulator for USB signal voltage. It needs a 220nF connected to pin VUSB. I'm wondering how USB is working at all when connecting VUSB to GND...

Comment: @sweber Thanks for mentioning that issue, but in anyway, the I2C stalls in I2C_Start

Comment: More: the caps at the crystal are connected to 5V via 10k. The same net connects to SCL or SDA. I'm astonished USB works at all without I2C, but as soon as you use I2C, you'll totally mess up with the clock, and USB does not like that. The caps need to be connected to GND as close as possible.

Comment: @sweber Fixed that problems, still I2C doesn't work at all, stall and stucks! thanks so much for your comments

Comment: @sweber I have updated the schematic in the post

Comment: @sweber I also messed up with the clock Inputs, and I fixed that, still

Comment: Another one: The crystal should be connected to OSC1 and OSC2, i.e. pins 9 ad 10. But this should not matter for the simulation...